# simple jquery selector doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

So I have this script on (http://clubmoving-wp.punct.ro/):

```
$('#scheduleBox .selectCity select option').click(function() {
        var cityToShow = $(this).attr('value');
         switch(cityToShow) {
            case '0':
                $('.bucuresti, .cluj, .otopeni, .iasi').show();
                break;   
            case '1':
                $('.cluj, .otopeni, .iasi').hide();
                $('.bucuresti').show();
                break;
            case '2':
                $('.cluj, .bucuresti, .iasi').hide();
                $('.otopeni').show();
                break;
            case '3':
                $('.bucuresti, .otopeni, .iasi').hide();
                $('.cluj').show();
                break;
            case '4':
                $('.bucuresti, .otopeni, .cluj').hide();
                $('.iasi').show();
                break;
        };
    });
```

that needs to show or hide activity by city. it works just fine in ff but no chrome

the actual script is in the gears.js

thank you

Comment: Could you make a fiddle replicating the problem?

Comment: solved, Chrome doesn't know to click on option, only on parent select and get the val from select and not option value, etc etc etc.

solved, thanks anyway

Comment: and you should be using `change` instead of `click`

Comment: Hi Vlad, if it is solved could you add an answer and accept it? Otherwise the question will remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#scheduleBox').on('change', '.selectCity', (function() {
        var cityToShow = $('option:selected', this).val();
         switch(cityToShow) {
            case '0':
                $('.bucuresti, .cluj, .otopeni, .iasi').show();
                break;   
            case '1':
                $('.cluj, .otopeni, .iasi').hide();
                $('.bucuresti').show();
                break;
            case '2':
                $('.cluj, .bucuresti, .iasi').hide();
                $('.otopeni').show();
                break;
            case '3':
                $('.bucuresti, .otopeni, .iasi').hide();
                $('.cluj').show();
                break;
            case '4':
                $('.bucuresti, .otopeni, .cluj').hide();
                $('.iasi').show();
                break;
        };
    });
```

Make the following changes and you should be good to go!